# php pg_query() not working?

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm very new to Postgresql.what is this error?

Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\torf.php on line 25

```
class user {

private $link=null; 

private function connect() {
    if ($this->link == null || !pg_ping($this->link) ) {
        $this->link = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=bigchance user=postgres password=lamp");
    }
}

public function user() {
    $this->connect();
}

public function new_id() {
    $id=0;
    $result = pg_query (user::connect(), "select * from user order by id desc limit 1 " );
    if ($result != false && pg_num_rows($result>0))  {
        $id= pg_fetch_result($result,0,0);
    }
    $id++;
    return $id;
}

public function insert( $email,$password ) {
    $id=$this->new_id();
    $result=pg_query(user::connect(),"insert into user (id,email,password,ip,created_td) values ('2','{$email}','{$password}','0','0')  ");
    return pg_affected_rows($result);
}
}
```

I'm using `$this->connect()` but there was an error :(

Comment: $result = pg_query (user::connect(), "select * from user order by id desc limit 1 " );

Comment: or
  $result=pg_query(user::connect(),"insert into user (id,email,password,ip,created_td) values ('2','{$email}','{$password}','0','0')  ");

my problem: 'user::connect()' how to connect?

Comment: You should call your constructor `function __construct`, not `function user`; the one you've used dates from PHP4, and may be removed in future. Also, `$this->connect()` rather than `self::connect`, since it's non-static (references `$this`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the result of the `connect` function as the parameter here: `pg_query (user::connect(), ...`, but it has no `return` statement, so will evaluate to `null`.

You need to call `$this->connect()` once (which you already do in the constructor), and then pass `$this->link`, as in `pg_query($this->link, ...`

Comment: damn i was posting the same answer :D

Comment: @Bob0t Sorry, hate it when that happens :)

Comment: you added `return $this->link` at the end of the `connect()` function and this failing ?